# How to use JLink to connect and read data from Tableau Hyper using Hyper API?

Tags: dataset, windows, java, api

First of all, [here](https://tableau.github.io/hyper-db/docs/releases#download) is the link to download the API for Java for Windows.

I initially wanted to use `NETLink` since I have some experience with it but they have deprecated the API for `.NET`.

But `JLink` might be the only option now. I am not familiar with `JLink`, if someone could create a minimal example for reading data from the example `.hyper` file that comes with the API download for Java located: `tableauhyperapi-java-windows-x86_64-release-main.0.0.17782.r044377f2\examples\data\superstore_sample.hyper`.

Even replicating the example code that is written in Java that comes with the API download.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated!

Comment: According to the information at the site, C++ and python are also supported. C++ can be interfaced to Mathematica through LibraryLink, ForeignFunctionLoad, etc. Python is available via ExternalEvaluate. If you want to use Java and JLink, I'd recommend taking a look at the Tech Note in the documentation. Maybe look at the example programs first to get a rough idea of how it works. There are syntax differences between Java and Mathematica ([] vs (), @ vs a '.' for method calls, etc.), but it's fairly straightforward to call java classes/methods from Mathematica.

Comment: ExternalEvaluate also supports Java, and is an alternative to using JLink; you can call Java code directly, or python etc. So for example, if you wanted to run the stie's python exmaple, you could use ExternalEvaluate to call the .py file directly and get the output in your notebook.

Comment: @jdp Thank you for your responses. I think I am close to getting `Java` version working. I am thinking about `C++` version but in their folder, they provide `.lib` but there is also a `bin` folder that has a `.dll`. In their instructions, they mention we have to compile using `cmake`. I don't want to do any compiling. Also `Python` I feel is a slow language to process large volumes of data. Do you think `C++` via `ForeignFunctionLoad` would be more performant compare to `Java` via `JLink`?

Comment: @jdp Also is the `C++` version going to be cross-platform? Are `.dll` compiled to work on any platform or there are specific `.dll` for every platform?

Comment: Code is compiled for a specific operating system, so your .dll is for Windows only. I.e. for Linux, you compile to a .so (shared object) etc. Regarding compiling, they likely provide you with a Makefile or its equivalent, so compiling would involve typing a command and letting the script run. The script will check what software is installed, set up a configuration for your system, and compile without any intervention required on your part. Usually. I don't know how much performance difference there might be between C++/Java. You do have the option of calling Java classes directly from ..

Comment: ExternalEvaluate. In the documentation, under Details, the third bullet lists choices for sys. Click on the gray "Java" in the left side of the column. That takes you to a page where they show examples of how to use Java in this function. It's a bit like issuing commands from a shell. You can load classes and call class methods directly. Regarding performance, both Python and Java are considered "slower" than C++, but it's not clear how relevant that is. If you're interfacing with the API and want to read/transfer the data, the python code will set up the transfer, but may not process it.